# Removing baseboard heater and installing elec oven on that wall

Tags: wiring, oven, baseboard

We are purchasing a home that has a baseboard heater on the wall that will be ideal for an elec oven can I just remove it and use that wiring for the oven socket?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

- There are 120V and 240V baseboard heaters. Your oven will almost certainly be 240V.
- Baseboard heaters basically max out at 1500W. Ovens are more 2000W+.
- The baseboard circuit probably had other things on it.

I'm ignoring the code issues, because I don't know the code, but I'd say the wiring is probably not good enough on a technical level. If this happened to be a 240V, 2500W heater on a dedicated circuit, it might be worthwhile to check the code, but anything less beefy than that isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! So we would need to run new wiring to install the oven and “cap” the baseboard heater wiring, or move it to the other side of the doorway where Id probably want it. Sound somewhat in the right direction?

Comment: That sounds reasonable.